# VBA Paste Data After Last Row Issue

Tags: vba, excel

I am compiling data from multiple worksheets to place on one consolidated sheet.  The first sheet is easy because I can paste the entire sheet however after that it becomes tricky as I only need from A5-H### as I no longer need the header.  I then need to paste this information at the bottom of the previous paste.  I am getting a Range of Object "_Global" failed for the 'Range(lastRow).Select'.  The issue is when I look at it in the debugger it is coming up with the correct row number.  What am I doing wrong?

```
Sheets(1).Select
Cells.Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Consolidation Sheet").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets(2).Select
Range("A5:A925").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Consolidation Sheet").Select
Range("A5").Select
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Range(lastRow).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need your `Range` statement in the following form (for example):

```
Range("A1").Select
```

So since you've got the row number (`lastRow`), you just need to add the column reference too:

```
Range("E" & lastRow).Select
```

---

*Extra info*

[Avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) by referring directly to the worksheets/ ranges you want to deal with

```
Sheets(1).Cells.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Consolidation Sheet").Range("A1")

With Sheets(2)
    .Range(.Range("A5:A925"),.Range("A5:A925").End(xlToRight)).Copy
End With

With Sheets("Consolidation Sheet")
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).PasteSpecial
End With
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I had originally tried Range(lastrow, "A") and was clearly so close but also so far away from success.